# Python: replace backward values in an efficient way

Tags: python, str-replace

Suppose I have the following **string** (it is NOT a dictionary)

```
"RandomText...Name1: a, randomtext, Name2: b, Value:1, randomtext Name1: c, Name2: d, Value:2, Name1: e, Name2: f, Value:3, ...RandomText"
```

Which is, in your opinion, the most efficient way to look for "Value:x" where x is any number and replace **only** the previous Name1 with "test"?

For instance if x is 2 I will have in the end:

```
"Randomtext...Name1: a, randomtext, Name2: b, Value:1, randomtext, Name1:test, Name2: d, Value:2, Name1: e, Name2: f, Value:3, ...RandomText"
```

They are strings and cannot be expressed as dictionarys or other python objects.

Comment: That's not a string, perhaps you are looking for a dictionary. Please do a Python tutorial

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do just that? (Replacing Name1 before a certain Value sounds very abritrary.)

Comment: >"They are strings and cannot be expressed as dictionaries or other python objects." – why not?

Comment: Because I am simplyfing the problem. In reality is not as simple as that butit could be "random text name1a randomtext name2b random random randomtext value2" where random text is anything. And there are a lot of narratives in random order

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [***re.sub()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function with specific regex pattern (just for your test case):

```
import re

s = "RandomText...Name1: a, Name2: b, Value:1, Name1: c, Name2: d, Value:2, Name1: e, Name2: f, Value:3, ...RandomText"
x = 2
result = re.sub(r'(Name1: )[a-z](?=, Name2: [a-z]+, Value:'+ str(x) +')', '\\1test', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
RandomText...Name1: a, Name2: b, Value:1, Name1: test, Name2: d, Value:2, Name1: e, Name2: f, Value:3, ...RandomText
```

---

`(?=...)` - positive lookahead assertion, ensures that `Name1` substring is followed by `Name2` and `Value`(with needed value) substrings/attributes

Comment: Nice, I was writing a complex regex with lookarounds, but didn't notice that `Name1, Name2, Value` are always in the same order.